# Paypal IPN Integration with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have managed to setup a form that takes a users details then, upon submission, a paypal payment is taken before adding the details to my mySQL database.

Here is my html:

```
<form id="paypal_form" class="paypal" action="payments.php" method="post" target="_blank">
Membership:
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Membership">
<select name="os0">
<option value="Level 1">Level 1 - £21.00 GBP</option>
<option value="Level 2">Level 2 - £25.00 GBP</option>
<option value="Level 3">Level 3 - £65.00 GBP</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="title" value="" />
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<input type="text" name="surname" value="" />
<input type="text" name="address_1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="address_2" value="" />
<input type="text" name="address_3" value="" />
<input type="text" name="county" value="" />
<input type="text" name="postcode" value="" />
<input type="text" name="job_title" value="" />
<input type="text" name="organisation" value="" />
<input type="text" name="email" value=""  data-type="email"/>
<input type="text" name="phone" value="" />
<input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" />
<input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input name="lc" type="hidden" value="UK" />
<input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="GBP" />
<input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
<input name="payer_email" type="hidden" value="customer@example.com" />
<input name="item_number" type="hidden" value="123456" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Payment" class="button large orange" />
</form>
```

Here is my payments.php file:

```
    <?php

    // Database variables
    $host    = "localhost"; //database location
    $user    = "user101"; //database username
    $pass    = "login"; //database password
    $db_name = "db101"; //database name

    // PayPal settings
    $paypal_email = 'MY PAYPALL EMAIL';
    $return_url   = 'MY THANKS PAGE';
    $cancel_url   = 'MY CANCEL PAGE';
    $notify_url   = 'LINK TO PAYMENTS.PHP';

    $item_name   = 'Test Item';
    $item_amount = 0.01;

    // Include Functions
    include("functions.php");

    //Database Connection
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_name);

    // Check if paypal request or response
    if (!isset($_POST["txn_id"]) && !isset($_POST["txn_type"])) {

        // Firstly Append paypal account to querystring
        $querystring .= "?business=" . urlencode($paypal_email) . "&";

        // Append amount& currency (£) to quersytring so it cannot be edited in html

        //The item name and amount can be brought in dynamically by querying the $_POST['item_number'] variable.
        $querystring .= "item_name=" . urlencode($item_name) . "&";
        $querystring .= "amount=" . urlencode($item_amount) . "&";

        //loop for posted values and append to querystring
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $querystring .= "$key=$value&";
        }

        // Append paypal return addresses
        $querystring .= "return=" . urlencode(stripslashes($return_url)) . "&";
        $querystring .= "cancel_return=" . urlencode(stripslashes($cancel_url)) . "&";
        $querystring .= "notify_url=" . urlencode($notify_url);

        // Append querystring with custom field
        //$querystring .= "&custom=".USERID;

        // Redirect to paypal IPN
        header('location:https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' . $querystring);
        exit();

    } else {

        // Response from Paypal

        // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i', '${1}%0D%0A${3}', $value); // IPN fix
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        // assign posted variables to local variables
        $data['item_name']        = $_POST['item_name'];
        $data['item_number']      = $_POST['item_number'];
        $data['payment_status']   = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $data['payment_amount']   = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $data['payment_currency'] = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $data['txn_id']           = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $data['receiver_email']   = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $data['payer_email']      = $_POST['payer_email'];
        $data['custom']           = $_POST['custom'];

        // post back to PayPal system to validate
        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

        $fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

        if (!$fp) {
            // HTTP ERROR
        } else {

            fputs($fp, $header . $req);
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $res = fgets($fp, 1024);
                if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {

                    // Used for debugging
                    //@mail("you@youremail.com", "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Verified Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");

                    // Validate payment (Check unique txnid & correct price)
                    $valid_txnid = check_txnid($data['txn_id']);
                    $valid_price = check_price($data['payment_amount'], $data['item_number']);
                    // PAYMENT VALIDATED & VERIFIED!
                    if ($valid_txnid && $valid_price) {
                        $orderid = updatePayments($data);
                        if ($orderid) {
                            // Payment has been made & successfully inserted into the Database                              
                        } else {
                            // Error inserting into DB
                            // E-mail admin or alert user
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Payment made but data has been changed
                        // E-mail admin or alert user
                    }

                } else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0) {

                    // PAYMENT INVALID & INVESTIGATE MANUALY! 
                    // E-mail admin or alert user

                    // Used for debugging
                    //@mail("you@youremail.com", "PAYPAL DEBUGGING", "Invalid Response<br />data = <pre>".print_r($post, true)."</pre>");
                }
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Here is my functions.php file:

```
    <?php
    // functions.php
    function check_txnid($tnxid)
    {
        global $link;
        return true;
        $valid_txnid = true;
        //get result set
        $sql         = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `payments` WHERE txnid = '$tnxid'", $link);
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $valid_txnid = false;
        }
        return $valid_txnid;
    }

    function check_price($price, $id)
    {
        $valid_price = false;
        /*
        you could use the below to check whether the correct price has been paid for the product
        if so uncomment the below code

        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT amount FROM `products` WHERE id = '$id'");
        if (mysql_numrows($sql) != 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $num = (float)$row['amount'];
        if($num == $price){
        $valid_price = true;
        }
        }
        }
        return $valid_price;
        */
        return true;
    }

    function updatePayments($data)
    {
        global $link;
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `payments` (txnid, payment_amount, payment_status, itemid, createdtime) VALUES (
                    '" . $data['txn_id'] . "' ,
                    '" . $data['payment_amount'] . "' ,
                    '" . $data['payment_status'] . "' ,
                    '" . $data['item_number'] . "' ,
                    '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "'
                    )", $link);
            return mysql_insert_id($link);
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Here is my MySQL Query which sets up my database table corrrectly:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payments` (
      `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `txnid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `payment_amount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
      `payment_status` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `itemid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `createdtime` datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I'm happy with the way it all works and info does pass through into my database following successful payment. My questions however, is how do i also send the additional html form fields, such as name, surname, address_1, to the mySQL database?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I think i need to edit the functions.php and payments.php files but i'm not experienced in mysql and don't know how to go about it without breaking the process that seems to work so far.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that needs doing is creating the extra fields into the mySQL table, so we change the SQL query to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payments` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txnid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `payment_amount` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `payment_status` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `itemid` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `createdtime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `customer_title` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `customer_name` varchar (50) NOT NULL,
  `customer_surname` varchar (50) NOT NULL,
   `customer_address_1` varchar (50) NOT NULL,
   `customer_address_2` varchar (50) NOT NULL,
   `customer_address_3` varchar (50) NOT NULL,
   `customer_county` varchar (50) NOT NULL,
   `customer_postcode` varchar (10) NOT NULL,
   `customer_job_title` varchar (50) NOT NULL,
   `customer_organisation` varchar (50) NOT NULL,
   `customer_email` varchar (150) NOT NULL,
   `customer_phone` varchar (15) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

We then need to change the posted variables section of payments.php to grab the extra variables.

```
     // assign posted variables to local variables
    $data['item_name']        = $_POST['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']      = $_POST['item_number'];
    $data['payment_status']   = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $data['payment_amount']   = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $data['payment_currency'] = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $data['txn_id']           = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $data['receiver_email']   = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $data['payer_email']      = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $data['custom']           = $_POST['custom'];

    $data['customer_title']     = $_POST['title'];
    $data['customer_name']      = $_POST['name'];
$data['customer_surname']       = $_POST['surname'];                
    $data['customer_address_1']     = $_POST['address_1'];
    $data['customer_address_2']     = $_POST['address_2'];
    $data['customer_address_3']     = $_POST['address_3'];
    $data['customer_county']        = $_POST['county'];
$data['customer_postcode']      = $_POST['postcode'];
    $data['customer_job_title']     = $_POST['job_title'];
    $data['customer_organisation']  = $_POST['organisation'];
    $data['customer_email']     = $_POST['email'];
    $data['customer_phone']         = $_POST['phone'];
```

The last part is to change the updatePayments function in functions.php

```
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `payments` (txnid, payment_amount, payment_status, itemid, createdtime, customer_title, customer_name, customer_surname, customer_address_1, customer_address_2, customer_address_3, customer_county, customer_postcode, customer_job_title, customer_organisation, customer_email, customer_phone) VALUES (
                '" . $data['txn_id'] . "' ,
                '" . $data['payment_amount'] . "' ,
                '" . $data['payment_status'] . "' ,
                '" . $data['item_number'] . "' ,
                '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "' ,
                '" . $data['customer_title'] . "' ,         
                '" . $data['customer_name'] . "' ,          
                '" . $data['customer_surname'] . "' ,                   
                '" . $data['customer_address_1'] . "' ,    
                '" . $data['customer_address_2'] . "' ,     
                '" . $data['customer_address_3'] . "' ,    
                '" . $data['customer_county'] . "' ,       
                '" . $data['customer_postcode'] . "' ,      
                '" . $data['customer_job_title'] . "' ,     
                '" . $data['customer_organisation'] . "' ,  
                '" . $data['customer_email'] . "' ,         
                '" . $data['customer_phone']  . "'     
                )", $link);
        return mysql_insert_id($link);
```

And that should, unless ive messed up, store your extra information.